# How to reload library to different version at runtime ? C#

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, reload

I am working on addon for SAP Business One, written in C#, Visual Studio, but the problem should not be limited to this occasion.

So I am adding a dll library "Sap.Data.Hana v3.5" as usually by Add reference in Solution Explorer. This one is a version of 1.0.112.0.
Specific version is set as false in properties of this.

Then in some circumstances I would like to use same library but in different version (1.00.120.042.111).
So I am trying to load it by this code:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles"), @"sap\hdbclient\ado.net\v3.5\Sap.Data.Hana.v3.5.dll"));
```

then later in code I am using a method (`Sap.Data.Hana.HanaConnection(conn.ToString())`) from this library.
And I am getting such an error:

```
"Exception message: Version mismatch: C:\Program Files\sap\SAP Business One\AddOns\CT\ProcessForce\Sap.Data.Hana.v3.5.dll (1.0.112.0), C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\libSQLDBCHDB.dll (1.00.120.042.111).
Exception stack trace:    at Sap.Data.Hana.HanaUnmanagedDll.CheckDllVersion(FileVersionInfo verDll, String dllPath)"
```

As I assume, but I am not sure the old version of library still exists in such an assembly and this is the problem.

However loading this library (in original version) should be lazy loaded !, so until this time it should not be loaded actually.

Anyway know how I can dynamically reload library to different version from the standard one in reference's assembly ?
Anyone know such a hack or way I should go ?

Regards

Comment: You just discovered part of why API's are a thing.   If you have data you want handled differently based on situation, you either need another app to serve up the options (a la WebAPI) and let your core code make the decision on how it connects, or you need to use dependency injection as a workaround.  Either way, using two versions of a library in one app is asking for maintenance hell.  I'd rethink the plan.  If you absolutely must do it, I'd say make two consuming sub-applications as part of your overall Solution and execute the one with the connection you want based on your parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is kind educative for me.
The issue is however more complex, no webapi exclusive for this issue is possible, neither duplication of project. Because projects are already quite heavy. If someone have a single trick for such a situation, even not beuatiful in architectural way please share with me.

Comment: The problem is, beyond just being a confusing mess to maintain, a problem with the fact that we're talking compiled code and not interpreted code. You'll need to ensure both libraries have different file names and load them both at the same time, and somehow merge the two files' versions of the namespace.  Visual Studio's project files are essentially made to actively prevent what you're trying to do, which is why I suggested a re-design.  What is the functional difference between the two libraries?  If I knew more about the functions you want/don't want, I might have some solid advice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your support. What I did is I have used event handler called AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve.
Then I am loading such a library in the moment my function is called by event handler. And it is probably called if it doesn't found specific url in gac, neither application's folder.